# How does CPU addressing the next instruction immediately after switching into protection mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, memory-segmentation, protected-mode

I've been working on the Lab1 of MIT6.828. I've got a question about the code used for switching to protection mode.
Here is the assembly code

```
  # Switch from real to protected mode, using a bootstrap GDT
  # and segment translation that makes virtual addresses 
  # identical to their physical addresses, so that the 
  # effective memory map does not change during the switch.
  lgdt    gdtdesc
  movl    %cr0, %eax
  orl     $CR0_PE_ON, %eax
  movl    %eax, %cr0

  # Jump to next instruction, but in 32-bit code segment.
  # Switches processor into 32-bit mode.
  ljmp    $PROT_MODE_CSEG, $protcseg
```

When executing code `movl    %eax, %cr0`，the IP register contains the physical address instruction `ljmp    $PROT_MODE_CSEG, $protcseg`

However, after the execution of `movl    %eax, %cr0`, the CPU is running on protection mode, but the value of CS and IP register does not change.

So, after the executiong of `movl    %eax, %cr0`, it must fetch the instruction using the values of CS and IP register, how could it work?

(I mean on protection mode, cpu addressing instructions using the segment selector stored in CS register, but the now the value of CS register is not a valid segment selector, so it can't get the right physical address using an invalid segment selecotr)

I've read the Intel architecture manual, but I can find the answer.

Comment: `Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual` Volume 3 Chapter 3.4.3 gives some hints on why this works.

Comment: This is the magic of the segment descriptor cache on the 286+. The value you see in the visible registers (CS, DS, ES, SS, FS, GS) is not really used after it has been loaded with a new value. In real mode loading DS with the value 0x7c0 sets the `base` in DS's descriptor cache to the value being loaded * 16. So the hidden `base` is set to 0x7c00 (0x7c0 * 16). This also applies when loading CS with a value too (ie: using a FAR JMP).

Comment: As an example let us say you are in real mode and CS was set to 0x7c0 (the descriptor cache will have a base of 0x7c00). Once you do the `mov cr0, eax` (with protected mode on) the processor computes a new IP from the current base of CS (0x7c00) and adds it to the IP of the next instruction after the `mov`. So even though CS still has a value of 0x7c0 the processor has calculated a proper linear address to execute.

Comment: The Intel manual is a good place for info, but I also recommend Robert Collins article on the hidden descriptor cache here: http://www.rcollins.org/ddj/Aug98/Aug98.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The segment base address (and other stuff associated with a segment) only change when you write the associated segment register, in a way that depends on what mode you were in when the write happens.  (This is why ["unreal" mode](https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode) works).

Until `ljmp`, nothing writes CS so the **CPU is still decoding in 16-bit mode, from the same CS:IP resolving to the same linear address** as if that `mov` to `cr0` hadn't had the protected-mode bit set.

Writing CR0 doesn't reinterpret CS as a segment selector and index the GDT with it, or any of the other segment registers.

Intel calls the segment register internals a "descriptor cache", but they're not really like the normal caches: they never invalidate themselves (e.g. in power-saving sleep states) and reload.  They're more like registers and are part of the architectural state: they keep whatever value they were written with, regardless of whether the GDT / LDT entry they index (if any) matches their state or even exists.  See also *https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27035/how-can-a-32-bit-x86-cpu-start-with-reset-vector-0xfffffff0-even-though-it-start/27038#27038*